# How to handle errors with Express .listen() (in Typescript)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

Currently converting my project to use Typescript. My previously working code to launch Express in Node looks like this:

```
server.listen(port, (error) => {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.info(`Ready on port ${port}`);
});
```

With this I now get a Typescript error:

```
Argument of type '(error: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.
```

I've tried assigning a type to the argument such as `error: Error` or `error: any` but this doesn't solve the problem. What am I doing wrong here?

Also, since I'm new to Typescript, whilst I've found plenty of resources for learning Typescript generally, is there any where I should be looking to know how to deal with Typescript in scenarios more specific to npm packages?

Comment: `throw` is not a function.

Comment: @JackBashford my bad, typo. I've fixed the code in the question back to what I had working before. Still have the Typescript error though.

Comment: are you sure that `server.listen`s `callback` has a signature `(err)=>` ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no `error`¹.

```
 server.listen(port, () => {
   console.info(`Ready on port ${port}`);
 });
```

To listen for errors, use `server.listen(port).on("error", /*...*/)` ².

¹: The docs are quite nested:

The [Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html) say, that

> This method is identical to Node’s http.Server.listen().

Now [these docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen) say, that `htt.Server.listen` equals `Net.server.listen`.

And [that](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen) then says:

> This function is asynchronous. When the server starts listening, the 'listening' event will be emitted. The last parameter callback will be added as a listener for the 'listening' event.

Now the ["listening" event](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_listening) does not seem to raise any error.

²: Thats the recommended way I found in the [Express issuetracker](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2856).

Note that in most cases you don't want to handle the error, if the server crashes, it is very likely that the best option is to just restart the whole process.

Comment: I thought the same because the error says it expects `()=>{}` but we are giving `(err)=>{}`

Comment: Thank you!!!! You save my mind !!!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today, too. Here's the (breaking) change to the type definition:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/47063

That PR's author suggests that the proper way to handle listen errors is by registering a listener (as linked by Jonas above):

https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen

It sounds like the type definitions were a lie, and that parameter didn't really exist, so removing its use from your app should be a no-op. That's what I'm doing. (furthermore, I'm okay with errors like EADDRINUSE crashing my app, so I'm not adding any new error handling)

Answer (score -1):

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const port = 3000

app.listen(port, () => {
   console.info(`Your app is listening a http://localhost: ${port}`);
 });
```

npm install express
try this

Comment: We've to install `express` before running this code. Then please make it clear in your answer. The commentary around your code is not clear.

Comment: No info about handling errors?